# how to parse a LocaleDate to a specific pattern mentioned in the DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want the currentDate in the format `MMMM d, YYYY`

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy");
String createdOnDate = alertspage.createdondate().trim();
LocalDate Date = LocalDate.parse(currentDate, formatter);
```

Comment: `currentDate` is a `LocalDate` - that does not have a format - it only has a default format used when it is converted to `String` using its `toString()` method - you need to use the `DateTimeFormatter` to `format` the `LocalDate` as required

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

#### the today's date in the desired format

```
System.out.println(
    LocalDate.now().format(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "MMMM, d uuuu",
            Locale.ENGLISH
        )
    )
);
```

---

#### Explanation

You're attempt to retrieve *the currentDate in the format MMMM d, YYYY* does not work because you don't produce the `String` output.
Instead, you try to `parse(currentDate, formatter)`, wich cannot won't be working either due to an unexpected type of the first parameter/argument (expects a `String`, you pass a `LocalDate`), or — if `LocalDate.toString()` is used implicitly — it won't have your custom format.

### Demo

#### Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get today's date as LocalDate
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    // provide a DateTimeFormatter for the desired OUTPUT
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                        "MMMM d, uuuu",
                                        Locale.ENGLISH
                                  );
    // print the resulting LocalDate's toString() (implicitly)
    System.out.println("toString(): " + today);
    // print the resulting LocalDate formatted by the formatter
    System.out.println("formatted:  " + today.format(formatter));
}
```

#### Output

```
toString(): 2023-06-26
formatted:  June 26, 2023
```